# how to get last processed rows in cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am having table data like this below

```
+---------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
| BilliedAmount | paidamnt | AccAmount | addAmunt | 1stBC  | 2ndBC |
+---------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|      10358.00 |  1523.55 |   8725.41 |      460 |        |       |
+---------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|        222.00 |   103.84 |    118.16 |    73.76 | 222.00 | 99203 |
+---------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|      10358.00 |  1523.55 |   8725.41 |      460 |        |       |
+---------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|        222.00 |   103.84 |    118.16 |    73.76 |        |       |
+---------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
```

I am using cursor to process row by row in this kind of data

**Condition 1 :**

If 1st BC and 2nd BC are not there i need insert  this values into one table (BilliedAmount paidamnt    AccAmount addAmunt)

**Condition 2 :**

If 1st BC and and 2nd Bc  are there i need to insert  1st BC and 2nd Bc into other table

I am using  cursor so i need to check for previous value(check for 1st BC and 2nd Bc vaues) when cursor is processing for the current row and access those values and store it in a table..

Would any one please help on this, that would be very grateful to me. 
Many thanks in advance..

Comment: what do you mean by 1st BC and 2nd BC? are they columns or rows?

Comment: can you show us your cursor query ?

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking and how your data hangs together. I observe there are repeating values in the 4 rows but I cannot guess what 1stbc and 2ndbc are supposed to indicate or what I should do with the repeating values.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use *cursor* just use `INSERT` statement with `SELECT` statement

```
insert into newtable1(BilliedAmount, paidamnt, AccAmount, addAmunt)
select BilliedAmount, paidamnt, AccAmount, addAmunt
from table
where 1stBC is null and 2ndBC is null -- 1STBC and 2ndBC are not there

insert into newtable2(1stBC, 2ndBC)
select 1stBC , 2ndBC
from table
where 1stBC is not null and 2ndBC is not null -- 1STBC and 2ndBC are there
```